# How do you read a set of atomic propositions?

Tags: logic, model-checking, ctl

[image]

I am given the above system for atomic propositions {a,b,c}.

I'm then meant to say if certain LTL formulae hold (such as `♢☐c`).

I understand what the LTL formulae mean (eventually forever c holds) but I have no idea how to read the diagram and relate it to the LTL.

I assume it's like a flow chart in that we start from the top left, `/{a}` and can go through the different states. But what does each of it mean divided by `a`?

Comment: i think the part im most confused about is what the slash means? surely its not divided by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like FSM/transduser rather than a Kripke structure. Input/output or more generally precondition/postcondition is a common notation for FSM and its kin.  precondition/postcondition `(a and b and ...) / (x and y and...)`. So `a` in the state `q1`. In next states either only `b` in q4 or `b and c` or q3. Might be of course `or` instead of `and` in precondition, otherwise the system might halt..